# why error message "$.effects is undefined"?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery's syntax, and this is likely a real noobie question....but I just do not see why I'm getting the error  "$.effects is undefined" when I just load this page. If anyone can see this, I would be much obliged...TIA, rixter

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="./development-bundle/ui/jquery.effects.pulsate.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(event){
           //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
         });
       });      

    function runEffect() {
      $("pulsate").effect( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    }

    // bind button to click event
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
    alert("Running effect...");
    runEffect();
    return false;
    });

    // callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
    $( "#effect" ).removeAttr( "style" ).hide().fadeIn();
      }, 1000 );
    };      

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <div id=effect>
      Show effects here...
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</a>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the scripts that you are trying to include? Namely, the jquery.effects.pulsate.js file. I certainly looks like something in the imports that is running and missing a library.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to load

> ./development-bundle/ui/jquery.effects.core.js

If you are just starting out I would recommend to just load the full version of jQuery UI instead of the separate development bundle files. Figuring dependencies out manually is a pain even when you know how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `$.effects` is a part of jQuery UI, which is not included in the core jQuery package. See http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods

You can customize and download a jQuery UI package on [the jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/download), then include it on your page in a separate `<script>` tag after jQuery.

Comment: Wow, thanks everybody...I was just going to post that I found the missing file that I needed to load...and see that 3 posts had already appeared! I will consider everyone's information to solve my problem....StackOverflow rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Plusate effect is done in the following way....

```
$(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
```

where 'this' is your div id or class.... for more info:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate